# C++ equivalent to R's set.seed() function

Tags: c++, r, random, rcpp

I would like to do the equivalent of R's `set.seed()` inside of a C++ function. How do I do this?

Note that I make this C++ function available in R via the Rcpp package. I would like `myfun(seed=42)` to return the same result each time it is called in R. I do not want to set the rng seed in R via `set.seed()` prior to calling `myfun` every time.

C++ file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double myfun(double seed) {
  std::srand(seed); // <-- this doesn't do what i want
  return R::rnorm(0,1);
}

/*** R
myfun(42)
myfun(42)
*/
```

This currently returns:

```
> myfun(42)
[1] 0.737397

> myfun(42)
[1] -0.02764103
```

What I want is:

```
> myfun(42)
[1] 0.737397

> myfun(42)
[1] 0.737397
```

Comment: If it were trivial we would have done it.  Call it from R, be done.  Else ... use a different RNG (family).  The code in base R is _complicated_ but can also be assumed to be correct. Pick your poison :)

Comment: Bummer, but OK.  Thanks, Dirk

Comment: There may be one odd way out. I think we added an option to leave the RNG-setting handshake we do from R to C++ alone (so "you are on your own" to keep the state of the RNGs sane) and you could then use `Rcpp::Function()` to call `set.seed()`.  But if you read this far you probably also convinced yourself already that that is brittle.   Now: What do you _really_ want to do?

Comment: I have a likelihood function in which I approximate an integral with an average (think multinomial probit with an accept-reject simulator).  I have the whole likelihood function coded up in C++ (using quite a bit of your Rcpp Sugar).  I just want to run `optim` from R on this function, but I don't want the random draws to change for each step taken by the optimizer (hence, I would like to set the seed inside of the C++ function).  It sounds like you're suggesting I wrap the C++ likelihood function in a simple R function that just sets the seed and then calls the C++ function... am I right?

Comment: You could use a non-R-based RNG and side-step the issue. Some are even faster:  RcppZiggurat, dqrng, ...

Comment: (And with `nloptr` you may get by without `optim()` ... but I am fully ignorant of whatever detailed issues you face there...)

Comment: I will look into those - thank you.  I'm quite new to C++ so I've been sticking to the world of Rcpp and optim() thus far.

Comment: That's not a approach -- robust and trusted. In which case you can just call `set.seed(123)` before calling `optim()` as you _are_ at the R level.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel -- I'm sorry but I don't understand the first sentence of your last comment.  Can you elaborate?  What is (or is not?) robust and trusted?

Comment: . Misses 'bad' ie not a bad approach.